# OnKeyDownEvent, typing characters or navigation

Tags: python, keyboard, wxpython, onkeydown

I have a little bit of a problem with the OnKeyDownEvent in wxPython.  I would like to act differently if the user is typing a character (like A, ), /, é, &, ...) and something else if it's just navigation (arrow keys, pageUp / pageDown, home/end, Ctrl + A or C or V, and so on).  Basically, I extract the modifiers and key code like this:

```
modifiers = e.GetModifiers()
key = e.GetUnicodeKey()
if not key:
    key = e.GetKeyCode()
```

But after that, well, that's kind of complicated.  For awhile, I tested the value of key:

```
if modifiers == wx.MOD_NONE and 0 < key < 255:
```

But that's not really effective... and not really pretty.  The right parenthesis for instance obviously has a key code greater than 255.

If you want to know why I do such a thing, the case study is a bit strange:  I have a huge text area in which text is entered programmatically (through connection to a distant server) but the user can type in this field.  **However**, when he does so, the cursor is moved to the last line... it's a bit like having a read-only text area except for the very last line.  I do that for accessibility reasons, I know it would be much more simple with two separate fields, but then, that's not as great for screen readers.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered defining the navigation keys in a `set()` and then checking if the key is in the navigation set, rather than testing for all of the other keys?
[Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: yes, it might be a solution, there are a lot of them but definitely less than the typing keys.

Comment: seems like the most obvious solution, should be accepted as the answer unless it doesn't meet your needs somehow